# Google results in XML/JSON - using the Custom Search Engine

Tags: xml, google-api

I'm having difficulty figuring out the right format for URL calls to a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) to return results in XML (using their [free service](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) for 100 calls per day).  I've set up an account and CSE. So now I have a public URL `https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=010317493064298903457:5bsx2whinf8` to search BBC news. But I can't figure out from the documentation how to develop the URL call to return results in XML format..

`https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=010317493064298903457:5bsx2whinf8&q=lon‌​don&start=0&num=10&output=xml_no_dtd` (based on the code provided in the CSE setup options) gives results in html frame.

`http://www.google.com/search?start=0&num=10&q=london&client=google-csbe&output=‌​xml_no_dtd&cx=010317493064298903457:5bsx2whinf8` (following the [XML API examples](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results)) also returns HTML.

Very grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: the note at the top of this page says the XML is only available for paid customers: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results

Comment: Perhaps, but the [Custom Search Control API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview) allows users 100 calls per day. It defaults to json which is equally usable.

Comment: from your post I thought you were only interested in the XML.. if JSON is an option, I think you have to use this method: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cracked. The minimum working URL formula I've got to work is a concatenation of the following strings:

- "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?"
- "q=" + search terms (e.g. "London+UK")
- "&cx=" + cx code of your [CSE](https://www.google.com/cse/all)
- "&key=" + your authorised API key [create an [API project](https://console.developers.google.com), then go to 'APIs & auth' and activate in 'Custom Search API']

You should end up with something looking like this:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=London+UK&cx=018475493028468909364:ldifwlodnso&key=AOgsDiRlzY7GDCKC5Th7yKutv-7Hd4-IDehl_Sp"
```

.. with results in json.

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=London+UK&cx=016594182476378821404:09qp1q0wip0&key=AIzaSyDwRQYXGcwjj-HUpxuGZFn9j8VeQ7PzKiY

Answer (score 1):

you can also change format into an ATOM webfeed by adding this to your url:
`&alt=atom`

... which gets you the XML output you originally requested.

Answer (score 0):

Google's [XML API reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results) says:

> This page refers to the XML version of the Custom Search API, which is available only to Google Site Search customers.

[Google Site Search](https://enterprise.google.com/search/products/gss.html) says:

> Google has discontinued sale/renewal of the Google Site Search since Apr 1 2017. The product will be completely shut down by April 1, 2018

This can help, but is still in alpha: http://serp-spider.github.io/